# Bootstrap, buttons become un-clickable within screen width 768px - 991

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know if this is a bug within the bootstrap framework, but any button I have within my application becomes un-clickable in the range of 768px - 991px wide. This width seems to fall into the ipad and galaxy portrait view. Is this a known bug with bootstrap? every other width works fine, except this range. I would be grateful if anybody could shed a little light on this.

Thanks in advance

John

Comment: Give <div class="clearfix"></div> after the end and see whether it solved the issue..

Comment: seems to have done the trick @Rajesh, thanks a lot, i wonder what is causing this? Anyways, if you answer it, i will accept the answer as the correct one, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Give it after the end and see whether it solved the issue..
This has happened with me once, so i used clearfix to solve it. I think due to resolution, the div becomes unresponsive for any click.

Comment: I think this is the only solution for this.