# Bootstraped links not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing an asp.net application and i have following code in my html markup:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Link 3 is working fine, but links 1 and 2 are dead, can't click on them.

When i change

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </div>
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-11 text-center">
                    <a href="#">3</a>
                </div>
```

or anything else, all links on page works fine.

I tried fiddle, and works fine, but not working in my development environment. Browsers (opera, ie, ff) are not showing any errors, and links just not work. Like they are just plain text.

Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: Works fine in this isolated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5ojromtq/

Comment: Presumably one or more tags in your development environment is mismatched. Nothing is wrong with the code you posted, see if you can reproduce it yourself on jsfiddle, otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have solved the problem, thanks to this this ([Bootstrap, buttons become un-clickable within screen width 768px - 991](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716295/bootstrap-buttons-become-un-clickable-within-screen-width-768px-991)) question

Solution is to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` so my code will become

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </div>
</div>
```